# Upload file with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit, retrofit2

I trying to do that a few days, and I really did everything..
Here is how request looks in Postman:
[image]

[image]

I am sure, that all GET parameters were writing correctly. The problem in how I sending a file to upload, I suppose.

```
            Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/ConstructSecure/d1940b05-76d1-4d98-b4b4-b04b8247c8cb.png");
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file);
            String fileName = file.getName();
            map.put("attachment\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"", requestBody);

            //GET parameters
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("inspectionUUID", inspectionUUID);
            params.put("noteUUID", noteUUID);
            params.put("attachmentUUID", attachmentUUID);
            params.put("noteType", noteType);
            params.put("modifiedTime", modifiedTime);

            Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(access_token,params,map);
            call.enqueue()....
```

Interface:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("api/MediaFiles/AddMediaFile")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
            /* GET params */ @QueryMap Map<String, String> params,
            @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map
    );
```

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spent a lot of time to search, how to send a file as byte-stream because all answers in web explain upload via RequestBody, but it's not working for my case.
So, here is the solution:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buf = new byte[in.available()];
    while (in.read(buf) != -1) ;
    RequestBody requestBodyByte = RequestBody
            .create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), buf);
    String content_disposition = "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"";

    //GET parameters
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("inspectionUUID", inspectionUUID);
    params.put("noteUUID", noteUUID);
    params.put("attachmentUUID", attachmentUUID);
    params.put("noteType", noteType);
    params.put("modifiedTime", modifiedTime);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(access_token, content_disposition, requestBodyByte, params);
```

Interface:

```
 @POST("api/MediaFiles/AddMediaFile")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,@Header("Content-Disposition") String content_disposition, @Body RequestBody photo,
            /* GET params */ @QueryMap Map<String, String> params
    );
```

Comment: How can I do if, I need to send more than one file in a single API hit.

Answer (score -1):

**Upload Image See Here click This Link**

http://mushtaq.16mb.com/retrofit_example/uploads/

[image]

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

class AppConfig {

    private static String BASE_URL = "http://mushtaq.16mb.com/";

    static Retrofit getRetrofit() {

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
}

========================================================
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Multipart;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Part;

interface ApiConfig {
    @Multipart
    @POST("retrofit_example/upload_image.php")
    Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                    @Part("file") RequestBody name);

    /*@Multipart
    @POST("ImageUpload")
    Call<ServerResponseKeshav> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                    @Part("file") RequestBody name);*/

    @Multipart
    @POST("retrofit_example/upload_multiple_files.php")
    Call<ServerResponse> uploadMulFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file1,
                                       @Part MultipartBody.Part file2);
}






https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzBKpZ4nzNzUMnJfaklVVTJkWEk
```